# How do I set my own ClassMetadata class for Doctrine?

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I want to create my own `ClassMetadata` class that extends from Doctrine's `ClassMetadata`.

So something like this:

```
MyCustomClassMetadata extends ClassMetadata
{
    public function myCustomMethodHere($args)
    {
        // code
    }
}
```

I use the `PHPDriver` and do not use doc block annotations to configure the ORM models.

So in my configuration folder for Doctrine entities I can do this:

```
$metadata->myCustomMethodHere($args);
```

Then I can get the custom metadata I set in an entity listener or something.

I was thinking the `PHPDriver` would allow me to set the `ClassMetadata`, but it only allows this if I know the entity of the Doctrine model:

```
public function loadMetadataForClass($className, ClassMetadata $metadata)
{
    $this->metadata = $metadata;

    $this->loadMappingFile($this->locator->findMappingFile($className));
}
```

So how would I achieve this without knowing the class name of the Doctrine model?